# How can you reference the checkoutRequestId from daraja API's mpesa express request dynamically

Tags: java, android, mpesa

I am working on an android app with an Mpesa payment module. I have already been able to generate the STKPush giuded by this tutorial on medium: https://medium.com/@lentimo/m-pesa-integration-on-android-part-2-75430ccda2fe . My goal is to be able to determine whether after receiving the STKPush, the customer processes the transaction to completion. Thus, I intend to use the Lipa Na M-Pesa Query Request API. To make a request here, you require the **checkoutRequestId** as one of the parameters. Thus my question, how can you reference the the **checkoutRequestId** from the code dynamically? Does anyone know of open source code pertaining Lipa Na M-Pesa Query Request API in android java  environment? And lastly, is there a simpler way to achieve the aforesaid goal?

Below is what i want to reference: 

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control:
no-store
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Length:
314
Content-Type:
application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:
Tue, 10 Mar 2020 18:25:08 GMT
{
  "MerchantRequestID": "7041-3944257-1",
  **"CheckoutRequestID": "ws_CO_100320202125091065",**
  "ResponseCode": "0",
  "ResponseDescription": "Success. Request accepted for processing",
  "CustomerMessage": "Success. Request accepted for processing"
}`

I am operating in sandbox environment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a successful request, in the onResponse block, parse the json response and extract the CheckoutRequestID. Keep reference to it, then when making the status query you can use it as required.

```
mApiClient.mpesaService().sendPush(stkPush).enqueue(new Callback<STKPush>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<STKPush> call, @NonNull Response<STKPush> response) {
                try {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        //Parse JSON response here to extract CheckoutRequestID
                    } else {

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<STKPush> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                //handle error
            }
        });
```

As from the [mpesa api docs](https://developer.safaricom.co.ke/docs#lipa-na-m-pesa-online-payment) an example of an accepted request response looks like the below

```
  {
    "Body":{
      "stkCallback":{
        "MerchantRequestID":"19465-780693-1",
        "CheckoutRequestID":"ws_CO_27072017154747416",
        "ResultCode":0,
        "ResultDesc":"The service request is processed successfully.",
        "CallbackMetadata":{
          "Item":[
            {
              "Name":"Amount",
              "Value":1
            },
            {
              "Name":"MpesaReceiptNumber",
              "Value":"LGR7OWQX0R"
            },
            {
              "Name":"Balance"
            },
            {
              "Name":"TransactionDate",
              "Value":20170727154800
            },
            {
              "Name":"PhoneNumber",
              "Value":254721566839
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```